# How to enable SSL on nginx?

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate

I have created ssl certificates for my site from sslforfree.com

I try to enable SSL on my NGINX server as follows, unfortunately I receive an error message as you may see at the bottom:

```
/etc/nginx/sites-available/default

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name myserver.com;

    listen 443;
    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /home/tolga/SSLcerts/ca_bundle.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /home/tolga/SSLcerts/private.key;
```

ERROR message:

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log

2017/10/06 11:29:55 [emerg] 13813#13813: SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file("/home/tolga/SSLcerts/private.key") failed (SSL: error:0B080074:x509 certificate routines:X509_check_private_key:key values mismatch
```

What might e the problem??

Comment: There is a problem with the key.... Post the steps you took to produce the csr and key. Along with the steps once you had the key from the CA

Comment: You have a mismatch between the private key and certificate. You are using the ca_bundle certificate instead of the SSL certificate issued for your domain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error in your config is that you have only one server paragraph. The server tells everything that a single connection needs to know. When you want SSL then you need to put that in a separate server paragraph. Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can remember (and using NginX for 3 years now) a single server paragraph can't listen on two different ports.

So your correct config would look like this if you also wish to redirect all HTTP to HTTPS:

```
server  {
        listen  80;
        server_name     myserver.com;
        return          301 https://myserver.com$request_uri;
}

server  {
        listen                  443 ssl;
        server_name             myserver.com.hu;

        ssl_certificate         /home/tolga/SSLcerts/ca_bundle.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/tolga/SSLcerts/private.key;

        root                    /var/www/html/com.myserver/public;

        error_log               /var/log/nginx/com.myserver/error.log;
        access_log              /var/log/nginx/com.myserver/access.log;

        index                   index.php;

        gzip  on;
        gzip_vary on;
        gzip_min_length 10240;
        gzip_proxied expired no-cache no-store private auth;
        gzip_types text/plain text/css text/xml text/javascript application/x-javascript application/xml;
        gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.";

        location..............
        location..............
        location..............
        location..............

}
```

**Also some advice for the future:**

- Put your crt and key files into `/etc/nginx/ssl/com.myserver.crt` and `/etc/nginx/ssl/com.myserver.key` (simply cause it is better organised this way)
- Enhance your security with the following code after ssl_ccertificate and before the root:

> ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
>
> ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
>
> ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EECDH:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256+EDH:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:EDH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA:AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-GCM-SHA256:AES256-SHA256:AES128-SHA256:AES256-SHA:AES128-SHA:DES-CBC3-SHA:HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4";
>
> add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000;
>   includeSubdomains; preload";
>
> ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

- Create your dhparam.pem file with the following command:

  openssl dhparam -dsaparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 4096

Comment: "When you want SSL then you need to put that in a separate server paragraph. Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can remember (and using NginX for 3 years now) a single server paragraph can't listen on two different ports." That's just plain simple wrong. Test for yourself.

Comment: Will do and if it works, I might reconfigure my configs. Even tho I think this way is is more pretty and understandable.

Comment: "Even tho I think this way is is more pretty and understandable.": Sure. And it's also helpful if you want to redirect `http` to `https`. But this doesn't lead to "can't listen". It might be that people have different use cases, so claims like these aren't that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I had 2 CRT files downloaded from sslforfree.com

In the nginx config, when I changed the certificate from ca_bundle.crt to certificate.crt problem is solved.

Comment: Forget sslforfree, go to the source directly. Let's Encrypt